# Exchange Web Services (EWS) or JavaMail Api to connect to Outlook Exchange Server - Java

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

we are switching from Lotus notes to Outlook 2013 and I'm working on a POC to connect to the Microsoft Exchange. I'm confused on which API to use to connect. *Requirement*:Basically I need to write Java Application to read inbox and get attachments and move the email to a different folder and in that folder I have to delete emails that are n days old.

1. Is EWS microsoft recommended? do we have support for bugs, updates etc
2. Can JavaMail Api be used to connect to Microsoft Exchange server.?
3. Can this(Requirement) be done thru reading the local .OST file, if yes how to read and can I move emails to different folder in .OST file.

Any help or suggestions on which API or method will be good in long run.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, EWS is the preferred API to access Exchange Server
2. Not a good idea - JavaMail supports POP3/SMTP/IMAP4 standards. These are supported by Exchange, but EWS provides a lot more Exchange specific functionality.
3. You can use Outlook Object Model (COM based).

Comment: If you only ever want to work with Exchange and no other mail servers, and you need to use Exchange specific functionality (which it doesn't sound like you do), then use EWS.  Otherwise, JavaMail should be able to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I started my POC with EWS. For the 3rd point- is there a Jar or API to read the .OST file in Java. and I have a concern that OST is a local copy, when it get sync with Exchange server, what happens to all my emails that I moved or deleted from the OST file.?

Comment: The format of the OST files is not documented. OST files can only be used in the context of the MAPI profile used to create it.